# SQL selection by column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

I am working with a really messed up DB that has a a lot of tables and some of the tables have huge numbers of columns with bad naming making this impossible to find anything specific.

I need a select operation for finding the table that has one of the columns equal to one specific value, by checking the values from each column of every table. Is that possible?

Comment: Answer is very specific to DBMS you're using. Right now you haven't specified it, so it's hard to give some useful answer.

Comment: Oups, sorry about that, i am using  MSSQL, and my development is done in MS SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is may be what you are looking for [Search all fields in SQL Server Database](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2010/02/19/Search+Every+Table+And+Field+In+A+SQL+Server+Database+Updated.aspx)

Comment: yea this should do it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the query: "select name_of_column from name_of_table where id = x"

Comment: The problem is that, you don't know the name of the column , or the table, just the value, and you make a huge search in all tables and for each table in all columns to see if you have a matching row with that value that you know

Comment: Can´t you search the name of the tablespaces?